# Using Performance Counters with Attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, enterprise-library, performancecounter

I'm looking for a way to simplify creating and using Performance Counters in our applications in order to run load tests and get the application specific information using the counters . It would be nice to do it using attributes. For example when a programmer puts an appropriate attribute on a method the method execution time is measured. So I'm looking for an attribute I can inherit that is activated by FW before and right after method call. Is there any attribute like this?

Thanks a lot, Dani

**Edit:** After some research I have found a `PerformanceCounterCallHandlerAttribute` from the EntLib. It seems to me that it is what I need but I'd like to know how exactly it works. I could not uderstand it from the documentaion I have found. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Aspect Oriented frameworks?

Comment: I've heared a little about PostSharp but for now I prefer to write something simple, dedicated to my application infrastructure and not to use commercial products

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683320/net-c-what-is-the-best-practice-for-securing-every-method/14683666#14683666). Not exactly what you are asking for but I believe same approach will work for you. It is all about handling before, after and on error events.